# IndexError: list index out of range with face recognition and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import face_recognition as fr

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Could not open webcam")


person1_image = fr.load_image_file("person1.JPG")
person2_image = fr.load_image_file("person2.jpg")
person1_image_encoding = fr.face_encodings(person1_image)
person2_image_encoding = fr.face_encodings(person2_image)

known_face_encodings = [person1_image_encoding, person2_image_encoding]
known_face_names = ["person1", "person2"]

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]

    face_locations = fr.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    face_encodings = fr.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

    for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):

        matches = fr.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)

        name = "Unknown"

        face_distances = fr.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)

        best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
        print(best_match_index)
        if matches[best_match_index]:
            name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    cv2.imshow('Webcam_facerecognition', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This works until it detects a face, at which point it says:

***if matches[best_match_index]:
IndexError: list index out of range***

I printed out the match index. It seems they are number larger than 2, like 62, 120 or something like that.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? Any feedback?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try instead of `best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)`something like

```
best_match_index = face_distances.index(min(face_distances))
```

??